# Favicon on blog.stackoverflow.com needs to be updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, blog, favicon

The favicon for the https://blog.stackoverflow.com/ website is still using the old white-matte favicon without the nice transparency.

It should be updated with the same favicon from the main SO site; or, to differentiate (in the browser) a blog tab from a SO tab, could use the grey icon from meta.

Answer (score 5):

But then how will you differentiate between the blog and the regular SO by the tabs icon when they're the same?

Different sites should have different icons.

Why are you trying to take away the blog's favicon? What if that's its style, shunning a *transparency* of sorts?

Instead of going with the meta colours, it should have its own colour version. Green maybe. There's not enough green in favicons.

If you check now, it's been [updated to transparentnessyness](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico).

Comment: The blog's `<title>` tag always says "Blog -- Stack Overflow", which should be enough. Or, it could be desaturated like the meta site, since the Blog is inherently meta discussion?

Comment: Doesn't always start with "Blog -- Stack Overflow". It changes with the posts and the categories. Could be you have a blog post and a question that have the same title. What then?

Comment: It didn't appear to be an issue for, say, the *first 11 months of the site*. My point is that the current icon looks _bad_, and should be corrected. I've edited the question to include the meta icon suggestion. I am guessing most people do not have a bunch of meta tabs open in their browser.

Comment: I'm not too worried about the blog and so sharing the same favicon. It won't derail my browsing. The blog stays open only long enough for me to read a post. SO stays open nearly all day.