# Favicon on blog.stackoverflow.com needs to be updated (again)

Tags: bug, design, blog, favicon

The [SO company blog favicon](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico) was [already fixed once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19882/favicon-on-blog-stackoverflow-com-needs-to-be-updated), back in 2009, to have proper alpha transparency so that it looks good on dark backgrounds too.  Apparently, it needs fixing again:

[image: Screenshot]

Please replace the ugly blog favicon with the [nice favicon used on SO](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico).